# Loading SQLite Database into Android App

Tags: android, sqlite

I am able to create, write and read an SQLite Database in my Android App. I have a copy of the Database that is fully populated with data, and I want to get that data into the App's Database. Is it possible to access my populated database from inside my App? Or can I at least create a copy of the populated database and then use that copy? Or do I need to do a .dump and put all the inserts into the Android code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application/9109728#9109728